# TFS 2010: how to reject gated checkin based on code duplication metric?

Tags: code-analysis

I'm running Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010, and using it to build a .NET 4.0 Solution.

I have enabled gated checkins, and we run our tests as part of the build, so the server rejects any checkin that causes the tests to break.

However, I want to take this a step further and reject checkins that contain more than a certain proportion of code duplication.

Is there a tool for TFS 2010, or perhaps an existing feature that I've missed, that would allow me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a fantastic idea!

I have not heard of this actualy being built, but the guys over at the [Community TFS Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/) would be best placed to point you in the right direction.

I can imagine that this Activity would be quite dificult to build :) and you may not want to tackle it yourself. I would make a [request on that project](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic).

Comment: Thanks - that's definitely the right approach (making a request to the Build Extensions guys) but we've actually abandoned TFS in favour of Subversion + VersionOne + TeamCity) so my motivation to do so approaches zero at this point :-)

Comment: What is about the last situation? Is it possible now?